# What mobile game is the store clerk playing in episode 10 of 13 Reasons Why?

Tags: game-identification

In Season 1 Episode 10 of Netflix's ***[13 Reasons Why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/13_Reasons_Why)***, you can see a store clerk playing a game on his cell phone around the 11:20 mark.

From the short clip, it seemed like a top-down MOBA made for mobile phones.

[image: Unknown mobile game]
<sup>animated gif [courtesy of Avery](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310367/what-mobile-game-is-the-store-clerk-playing-in-episode-10-of-13-reasons-why?noredirect=1#comment441486_310367)</sup>

What game is he playing, if it's a real game at all?

Comment: Are there any clearer screen grabs? Or is this the only one - I ask because it's kind of hard to tell based on this picture alone

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein I cropped the scene: https://gfycat.com/BadTartAmericancrow -- if you want to view it slower (8x etc), gfycat allows that: https://gfycat.com/BadTartAmericancrow?speed=0.125

Answer (score 1):

My conclusion from looking at the game in the image: **that is likely to not be a real game**.

From where the store clerk is tapping, it doesn't look like he has any goal in particular that he is trying to do with the game. I don't see any buttons or avatar either that he could be tapping or controlling.

My guess would be that this "game" is a placebo or something to make it seem the clerk is playing a game or being busy on his phone.

Hope this helped! Should I get any tips I will update my response.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back it up? There has already been an answer, now deleted, claiming it is a fake game without any sources

Comment: Not yet. This is from what I know. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @Wondercricket Say, should this game be a placebo, the producers probably wouldn't say anything about it. My answer is based on logical reasoning. Games will probably have a goal, correct?

Comment: It looks like he is scrolling around a map.  That doesn't give conclusive evidence that it's fake.  I also don't really see why there would be so many menu icons made for a fake game; or why someone would bother to make a fake game for such a small screen-time .  It would seem like a waste when they could likely get permission to use another game for free (hello free advertising!).  I don't think this is enough information to say it's a fake.

Comment: @redapple8787 FYI you're completely misusing the word placebo. Placebo is a medicine or procedure or an action that doesn't have any effect in theory but does have in practice. You can't describe a game as placebo.

Answer (score -4):

I think its dungeon run because the way he moves his finger and how it looks. I 
think its called dungeon run.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade. Can you share any links or images that confirm this?